# Oracle VM can't detect my usb support (the service isn't on the list)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb, virtualbox, virtual-machine

i'm using virtual box on linux ubuntu 16.04 in order to run windows 10 , everything is working perfectly fine except the fact that my usb support can't be detected on windows 10 but it is detected on linux, when i try to list the services in to stop the VM service and restart it again i can't find the name of the service on the list.

```
$ service --status-all
[ + ]  acpid
 [ - ]  alsa-utils
 [ - ]  anacron
 [ - ]  apparmor
 [ + ]  apport
 [ + ]  avahi-daemon
 [ + ]  binfmt-support
 [ + ]  bluetooth
 [ - ]  bootmisc.sh
 [ - ]  brltty
 [ - ]  checkfs.sh
 [ - ]  checkroot-bootclean.sh
 [ - ]  checkroot.sh
 [ + ]  console-setup
 [ + ]  cron
 [ + ]  cups
 [ + ]  cups-browsed
 [ + ]  dbus
 [ - ]  dns-clean
 [ + ]  grub-common
 [ + ]  hddtemp
 [ - ]  hostname.sh
 [ - ]  hwclock.sh
 [ + ]  irqbalance
 [ - ]  kerneloops
 [ - ]  keyboard-setup.dpkg-bak
 [ - ]  killprocs
 [ + ]  kmod
 [ + ]  lightdm
 [ + ]  lm-sensors
 [ + ]  lvm2
 [ - ]  lvm2-lvmetad
 [ - ]  lvm2-lvmpolld
 [ - ]  mountall-bootclean.sh
 [ - ]  mountall.sh
 [ - ]  mountdevsubfs.sh
 [ - ]  mountkernfs.sh
 [ - ]  mountnfs-bootclean.sh
 [ - ]  mountnfs.sh
 [ + ]  network-manager
 [ + ]  networking
 [ + ]  ondemand
 [ - ]  plymouth
 [ - ]  plymouth-log
 [ - ]  pppd-dns
 [ + ]  procps
 [ + ]  rc.local
 [ + ]  resolvconf
 [ - ]  rsync
 [ + ]  rsyslog
 [ - ]  saned
 [ - ]  sendsigs
 [ + ]  speech-dispatcher
 [ + ]  thermald
 [ + ]  tlp
 [ + ]  udev
 [ + ]  ufw
 [ - ]  umountfs
 [ - ]  umountnfs.sh
 [ - ]  umountroot
 [ + ]  unattended-upgrades
 [ + ]  urandom
 [ - ]  uuidd
 [ + ]  whoopsie
 [ - ]  x11-common
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the Guest Additions.